# Variable binding in a condition requires an initializer?

Tags: swift, xcode

in the Swift Playground I have: "You can use a shorter spelling to unwrap a value, using the same name for that unwrapped value." then,

```
   if let nickname {
    print("Hey, \(nickname)")
}
```

I receive "Variable binding in a condition requires an initializer" when I try to run it

Comment: What you're looking for is `if let nickname = nickname { print(nickname) }` or `if let n = nickname { print(n) }`. Something like that.

Comment: Be warn that the sortit is only available with swift 5.7 . How is declared nickname ? This may be the cause.

Comment: What you've posted is legal in Swift 5.7, but not in older versions of the language. In Swift <=5.6, you have to write `if let nickname = nickname`

Answer (score 0):

**Upgrade to Xcode 14.**

In Xcode 14, you can write this:

```
var nickname : String? = "Nick"

if let nickname {
    print("Hey \(nickname)")
}
```

and it'll work fine because you're using Swift 5.7. Xcode 13.x and earlier have older Swift versions which don't work with the abbreviated unwrapping form that you're trying to use.

Answer (score -2):

I think you should use `if let n = nickname { Print("\(n)")`

Comment: The question is in regards to a new feature of Swift 5.6 which let's you automatically unwrap a variable. Even so, there's a convention in Swift to use the same name for the unwrapped value as the original variable so while your answer may work, it's not really recommended to code this way. Code should be self commenting and a variable "n" for "name" is not self commenting.